# GEKKO throws Inequality Definition error in model without inequalities

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am trying to use GEKKO to solve a dynamic parameter identification problem.
For context it is a CSTR producing biodiesel in which I am trying to find the average reaction rate.

`x[3]` is the biodiesel fraction on the reactor output that I am trying to fit to `ymeas` that come from lab measurements. `u` is a matrix with the measurements of four load variables.

Given the following formaulation:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 36000, 3600)

ymeas = np.array([0.429, 0.429, 0.427, 0.429, 0.428, 0.429, 0.429, 0.428,  0.428, 0.429])

u = np.array([
    [2996.9, 2989.4, 2997.0, 3005.6, 3001.7, 2988.8, 2986.6, 3005.5, 2993.9, 2994.0,],
    [656.9, 656.8, 657.7, 658.8, 657.3, 660.2, 659.5, 662.0, 659.7, 659.0,],
    [333.1, 334.1, 332.6, 333.6, 331.0, 330.9, 331.0, 330.8, 331.7, 331.3,],
    [323.2, 324.2, 324.9, 325.9, 326.9, 327.11, 327.6, 327.6, 327.4, 326.8],
    ])

par0=0.046

m = GEKKO(remote=False)    # create GEKKO model

m.time = t # time points

M = np.array([0.853, 0.032, 0.092, 0.286,])
ro = np.array([954.0, 757.0, 1340.0, 844.0,])
cp = np.array([2110.0, 2785.0, 2556.0, 2146.0,])
xo = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0,])
xm = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0,])
vmol = M / ro
cpmol = cp * M

# create GEKKO constants
nc = 4
Mo = m.Const(value=0.853)
Mm = m.Const(value=0.032)
cpmolo = m.Const(value=cpmol[0])
cpmolm = m.Const(value=cpmol[1])
VR = m.Const(20)
dHr = m.Const(-6309)

# create GEKKO parameter
r = m.FV(value=par0)

u0 = m.Param(value=u[0, :])
u1 = m.Param(value=u[1, :])
u2 = m.Param(value=u[2, :])
u3 = m.Param(value=u[3, :])

# create GEKKO variables
x = m.Array(m.Var, 4)
x[0].value = 0.0031
x[1].value = 0.4235
x[2].value = 0.1432
x[3] = m.CV(value=ymeas)
x[3].FSTATUS = 1
T = m.Var(333.5500)

rx = [-r, -3*r, r, 3*r,]

# create GEKKO equations
To = u2
Tm = u3
No = m.Intermediate(u0/Mo/3600)
Nm =  m.Intermediate(u1/Mm/3600)
cpmolR = m.Intermediate(np.sum(x * cpmol))
nR = m.Intermediate(VR / np.sum(vmol * x))

m.Equation(nR*x[i].dt() == Nm*(xm[i] - x[i]) + No*(xo[i] - x[i]) + rx[i]*VR for i in range(nc))
m.Equation(nR*cpmolR*T.dt() == Nm*cpmolm*(Tm - T) + No*cpmolo*(To - T) + VR*(-dHr)*r)

# solve ODE
r.STATUS = 1
m.options.IMODE = 5 # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 3 # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)

print('Parameter identification: done!')
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 <generatorobject<genexpr>at0x7f88ecb7cf90>
 STOPPING . . .
```

I can't think of a way to fix this, because I did not define inequalities.

Anyone has ideas to fix this and get the solver to find `r`?

I tried create `x[3]` as an independent `y` and append to the `x` array but got a shape error in Intermediate equation `cpmolR = m.Intermediate(np.sum(x * cpmol))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m.open_folder()` and open the `gk_model0.apm` model file with a text editor. It shows that a generator is used for the 2nd-to-last equation.

```
Equations
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f9adc07bc10>
    ((((i9)*(i8)))*($v6))=((((((i7)*(i3)))*((p5-v6)))
           +((((i6)*(i2)))*((p4-v6))))+((((i4)*((-i5))))*(p1)))
End Equations
```

Use square brackets to make it a list of equations:

```py
m.Equation([nR*x[i].dt() == Nm*(xm[i] - x[i]) \
                          + No*(xo[i] - x[i]) \
                          + rx[i]*VR \
            for i in range(nc)])
```

There were a few other issues with the syntax that are resolved with this script:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 36000, 3600)

ymeas = np.array([0.429, 0.429, 0.427, 0.429, 0.428, 0.429, 0.429, 0.428,  0.428, 0.429])

u = np.array([
    [2996.9, 2989.4, 2997.0, 3005.6, 3001.7, 2988.8, 2986.6, 3005.5, 2993.9, 2994.0,],
    [656.9, 656.8, 657.7, 658.8, 657.3, 660.2, 659.5, 662.0, 659.7, 659.0,],
    [333.1, 334.1, 332.6, 333.6, 331.0, 330.9, 331.0, 330.8, 331.7, 331.3,],
    [323.2, 324.2, 324.9, 325.9, 326.9, 327.11, 327.6, 327.6, 327.4, 326.8]])

par0=0.046

m = GEKKO(remote=False)    # create GEKKO model

m.time = t # time points

M = np.array([0.853, 0.032, 0.092, 0.286])
ro = np.array([954.0, 757.0, 1340.0, 844.0])
cp = np.array([2110.0, 2785.0, 2556.0, 2146.0])
xo = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])
xm = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])
vmol = M / ro
cpmol = cp * M

# create GEKKO constants
nc = 4
Mo = 0.853
Mm = 0.032
cpmolo = cpmol[0]
cpmolm = cpmol[1]
VR = 20
dHr = -6309

# create GEKKO parameter
r = m.FV(value=par0)

u0 = m.Param(value=u[0, :])
u1 = m.Param(value=u[1, :])
u2 = m.Param(value=u[2, :])
u3 = m.Param(value=u[3, :])

# create GEKKO variables
x = np.array([None]*4)
x[0] = m.Var(0.0031)
x[1] = m.Var(0.4235)
x[2] = m.Var(0.1432)
x[3] = m.Var(0.429)
y = m.Param(ymeas)
T = m.Var(333.5500)

rx = [-r, -3*r, r, 3*r,]

# create GEKKO equations
To = u2
Tm = u3
No = m.Intermediate(u0/Mo/3600)
Nm =  m.Intermediate(u1/Mm/3600)
cpmolR = m.Intermediate(np.sum(x * cpmol))
nR = m.Intermediate(VR / np.sum(vmol * x))

m.Equations([nR*x[i].dt() == Nm*(xm[i] - x[i]) + No*(xo[i] - x[i]) + rx[i]*VR for i in range(nc)])
m.Equation(nR*cpmolR*T.dt() == Nm*cpmolm*(Tm - T) + No*cpmolo*(To - T) + VR*(-dHr)*r)

# minimize sum of squared errors
m.Minimize((x[3]-y)**2)

# solve ODE
r.STATUS = 1
m.options.IMODE = 5 # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 3 # collocation nodes
#m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=True)

print('Parameter identification: done!')
```

This produces a successful solution:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  1.65358E-05  2.02852E-03
    1  1.19327E-05  1.09210E-07
    2  1.18844E-05  3.12011E-10
    3  1.18844E-05  2.64239E-12
    4  1.18844E-05  2.64239E-12
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   1.279999999678694E-002 sec
 Objective      :   1.188444178924983E-005
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: These changes solve the issue. Thank you very much for your help!